# Как сделать такой скролл?

Tags: jquery, вёрстка

Нужен скролл, как тут:

[image]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Возможно прийдется jScrollPane юзать +кастумизация оного, но я не фанат.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примерно так

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #777;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: #777;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
{
    background-color: #393939;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Единственный минус - на Мозиле не пашет, но кому она нафиг нужна)). Главное на Safari и Chrome работает.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи  можно и для firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars. Пример https://jsfiddle.net/e3n81j79/

Comment: @soledar10 да работает, правда закругления не работают, но хоть так)